# Quantitavely replace digit (as counter) with string in sed

Tags: awk, sed, tr

Let's say i have the following file:

```
balloons:
 - 2
 - 3
```

Each number above should represents how many times i want to print the string. So for example I would like to process this to output as following:

```
balloons:
- red
- red
- blue
- blue
- blue
```

I only have red and blue balloons. The digits will vary from one file to another, so my search string would be a simple regex search `sed -e "/[[:digit:]]\+/ perform_my_action"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{idx[2]="red"; idx[3]="blue"}
/^-[ \t]+[0-9]+/{for(i=1;i<=$2;i++) print idx[$2]; next}
1
' file
```